# Show only MySQL columns that exist in queried table

Tags: php, mysql

I have several MySQL tables that are dynamically generated into a html table one table at a time through the code below. However, the tables don't have the same columns. i.e. One table has a description column, whereas the other does not.

Is the following code the best way to have all the possible MySQL columns among the various tables in the script but only show the MySQL columns that exist for the selected table? I feel like I'm redundant by writing "isset" for every column. Thanks!

```
<?php
$query = " SELECT * FROM $tablename ";

$query_select = mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_select)) {
?>

<table>
  <tr>

    <?php if(isset($row['name'])){ ?>
      <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if(isset($row['description'])){ ?>
      <td><?php echo $row['description']?></td>
    <?php } ?>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Be careful with your terminology here, you mean the columns are `NULL` rather than not having the columns at all?

Comment: I need the `<td>` to show whether the columns are null or not. I don't need to show the columns that don't exist on the MySQL table. Does it make sense?

Comment: I think its the `mysqli_fetch_fields()` function you are looking for, to retrieve the metadata (column names, datatypes) from a resultset. See the answer from Bill Karwin. He shows how to loop through all the columns in a resultset. (My answer would essentially be a duplicate of his answer.)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to make your code adapt to the fields in the result set:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$fields = mysqli_fetch_fields($result);
$myaliases = array(
  'column_id' => 'id'
);
?>
<table>
<tr>
  <?php foreach ($fields as $field): ?>
    <th><?php echo $myaliases[$field->name] ?: $field->name; ?></th>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>
<tr>
  <?php foreach ($fields as $field): ?>
    <td><?php echo $row[$field->name]; ?></td>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

---

Re comments:

I've added code above to print a table row for column headings.

I've also included an example of mapping a field name `column_id` to a table heading `id` in the output.  If I define no alias for a given column, it defaults to the original field name by using the PHP 5.3 operator `?:`

You could alternatively define column aliases in your SQL query like `SELECT column_id AS id ...`

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php

Comment: +1 I think this is what the OP was asking for, how to access the metadata in a resultset, given the "SELECT * FROM" in the query. The `mysqli_fetch_fields()` (or the OO-style `$result->fetch_fields()`) is how we get the metadata (column names and datatypes) from the resultset. There could also be a pass through $fields, before the first row, to print column names, as a header above the values.

Comment: I used `$field->name` to get the `<th>` names. How do I change their MySQL names? Like instead of it saying `column_id` it would say `ID`.

Comment: I just tested it and it works for me (PHP 5.3.15, MySQL 5.6.12).  Can you be more specific about how it is not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can `foreach` the array instead.

```
<?php
$query = " SELECT * FROM $tablename ";   

$query_select = mysqli_query($con,$query);
?>
<table>
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_select, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
  <tr>
    <?php foreach($row as $key => $value) { ?>
      <td><?=$value?></td>
    <?php } //Endforeach ?>
  </tr>
<?php } //Endwhile ?>
</table>
```

If you need to print labels you can also use an associative array and an additional iteration to do that as well.

```
<?php
$query = " SELECT * FROM $tablename ";
$keys = array('name' => 'Name Label', 'description' => 'Description Label');    

$query_select = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$i = 0;
?>
<table>
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_select, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
  <?php if($i == 0) { ?>
    <tr>
      <?php foreach($row as $key => $value) { ?>
        <td><b><?=$keys[$key]?></b></td>
      <?php } //Endforeach ?>
    </tr>
  <?php } $i++; //Endif ?>
  <tr>
    <?php foreach($row as $key => $value) { ?>
      <td><?=$value?></td>
    <?php } //Endforeach ?>
  </tr>
<?php } //Endwhile ?>
</table>
```

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array() adds both integer and named array keys by default, so this will print all the columns twice.

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop through the results. However, that would not perform any checks. Most likely, you'll have to do something like this, depending on what you're actually getting from the database.

```
<?php foreach ($row as $field): ?>
    <?php if ($field): ?>
        <td><?php echo $field; ?></td>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Edit: In keeping in line with the comment you added above, you could simply remove the if clause.

Comment: In this case, yes, it will. But your query will only return fields that actually exist, so you could just skip the if altogether if you just want to print out the rows that do exist for each table.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you need, 
but you can use indexes instead for the column instead of names:

```
<?php
   $query = " SELECT * FROM $tablename ";

    $query_select = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_select)) {
      echo $row[0] ." ".$row[1]." ".$row[2]
    }
?>
```

[mysql_fetch_array](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp)

possible formating:

```
<table> 
    <?php 
    $query = " SELECT * FROM $tablename ";
    $query_select = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_select)) { ?>
         <tr>
         <?php for(var $i=0; $i < count($row); $i++){ 
              echo "<td>". $row[i] ."</td>";
         } ?>
         </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```